# Loop over JSON in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON response that i am trying to loop over. The JSON response looks like this:-

```
req = requests.get("http://url")
     print(req.json())

{
'responseHeader': {'status': 0, 'QTime': 0}, 
'collections': 
['testing1', 'testing2', 'facebook', 'google', 'IG', 'reddit']
}
```

I am trying to output the collection names :-

So i tried this,

```
for x in req['collections']:
         print(x);
```

But i get `TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable`

I am new to Python so any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `req['collections']` => `req.json()['collections']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parsed json object is available from the [`.json()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) method of the response object. You need to look at the `collections` key *in this dict*, not in the response object.

Change `for x in req['collections']` to `for x in req.json()['collections']`

Answer (score 2):

Not indexing the proper value, change your code to the following

```
req = requests.get("http://url").json()

for x in req['collections']:
         print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

you need it to be `req.json()['collections']`